# В mySQL не отправляются данные из формы

Tags: php, mysql

Почему-то данные из формы никак не хотят лететь в бд,даже при условии того,что отчаявшись, я просто копирую код из разных гайдов и делаю всё в точности.
Прошу помощи,т.к. не могу продолжить освоение php без этого.

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name2" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="surname" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE" />
</form>

<?php
     $name2=$_POST['name2'];
     $surname=$_POST['surname'];
     $phone=$_POST['phone'];

     echo ' <br/>  You name: ' .$name2.
     '<br/>  You surname '.$surname.' 
     <br/>  You telephone: '.$phone. ' <br/>  <br/>  ';     



     $db  =  new  PDO('mysql:dbname=mydatabase; 
     host=localhost',"admin","1234",[ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ]);

     $sql="insert into `people` (name2,surname,phone) values 
     (:name2,:surname,:phone)";
     $sth=$db->prepare($sql);
     $sth->bindValue(':name2', $name2);
     $sth->bindValue(':surname', $surname);
     $sth->bindValue(':phone', $phone);

     var_dump($sql, md5($sql));

     $sth->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Файл как называется, в котором этот листинг ?

Comment: "add.php",тот же что и в action

Comment: Я перепробовал уже много вариантов,но ни один не работает,будто и не в коде проблема.Из бд данные выводятся отлично,а вот вводиться не хотят.

Comment: Добавьте последним параметром для `new PDO` вот это: `[ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ]`. Я очень косо смотрю на имя столбца name, которое вообще-то [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @Мелкий Поменял name на name2.Этот параметр нужно вставить через запятую после пароля бд?(первый раз сталкиваюсь с PDO)

Comment: Ошибки какие? `var_dump($sth->errorInfo());`

Comment: Верните обратно PDOException, который тут только что был =) Синтаксическая ошибка в запросе. Я её, правда, не вижу. Но раз mysql сказал ошибка, то спорить тут бесполезно. Сделайте `var_dump($sql, md5($sql));` надо понять, весь ли запрос виден или перед `) values` затесалось при копировании что-то лишнее на что обижается парсер

Comment: @rjhdby с этим errorInfo вот что выдало:

array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: @Мелкий Сделал правку.Ошибки там.Надеюсь всё правильно сделал.

Comment: Ну так ошибка поменялась, теперь другая ошибка. `Unknown column 'name2'`. Перевод нужен?

Comment: Исправил!)Спасибо.
Но осталось это: string(74) "insert into `people` (name2,surname,phone) values (:name2,:surname,:phone)" string(32) "f86448783ed8766b416ba8558daba848"

Comment: Вообще-то `name` это __keyword__, у __reserved__ word стоит `(R)`. Не вводите людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @Мелкий нет-нет.Всё работает.Спасибо что помогли человеку с кривыми руками.Не подскажите как отметить вопрос решённым?

Comment: Нужно написать ответ, потом отметить его галочкой.